# Instance creation in java

Tags: java, object

IN OBJECT CREATION,

Bike b =  new Honda();

For which class the object is created...for Honda or For Bike?

bike is parent class and honda is child class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An *object* of type `Honda` is created. The *variable* is of type `Bike`. The value of the variable is a reference - that reference must always either be the `null` value, or it must refer to an object of a type *compatible* with `Bike`, in order to be the value of the `b` variable. That's fine, because the `Honda` type is assignment-compatible with the `Bike` type.

If you print out `b.getClass()` for example, that will still show `Honda`, because that refers to the execution-time type of the object. But if there are any methods declared only by `Honda` (not by `Bike`) then you wouldn't be able to call them directly on `b`:

```
// This would be invalid, assuming that getHondaGarage is declared in Honda
String garage = b.getHondaGarage();
```

Even though the object itself (at execution time) supports the method, the *variable* being of type `Bike` means you can only access members declared by `Bike` and its superclasses.

Answer (score 4):

`Object` (or) Instance will be created for `Honda` class.

Left side of the `=` symbol represents reference is of type `Bike` and right side is instance.

Answer (score 2):

An `Object` of type `Honda` is created.

More over the phrase **"instantiating a class"** means the same thing as **"creating an object."** When you create an `object`, you are creating an "`instance`" of a class, therefore "instantiating" a `class`.

Answer (score 1):

The object is of type `Honda`.

```
b instanceof Honda == true
```

The variable on the other hand is of type `Bike`

Answer (score 1):

`Object` of type `Honda` class will be created but it will be stored in a **variable** of type `Bike`, Make sure that `Bike` is the **Derived Class** of `Honda` ...